# How to scrape all elements from a table in a webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm playing around with the code below.  I'm just trying to get all elements from a table, and I thought the code below would do it, but all I get is a message that reads: 'None'

```
website_url = requests.get('https://google_cloud_platform.html').text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'p6n-table-full-width p6n-space-above-large p6n-table'})
print(My_table)
```

Here is an image of the item I am trying to pull in.

[image]

Maybe I need to look for some other kind of identifier.  I'm not sure, exactly, what to look for.  Is there a way to list all table names?  Maybe it actually has a different name, or ID, or some such thing.

I am starting to think it is not even a real table. When I run the script below, I get this: 'IndexError: list index out of range'.  That makes me think there is not even one table in the web page.  But, based on the screen shot that I posted, there is something called 'table class'.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://google_cloud_platform.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df[0].to_json(orient='records'))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't call `find_all`. Can you provide the full error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:1234")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')
for t in table:
    print(t.contents)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That gives me nothing at all, which is kind of what I suspected.  I don't know how to grab these web elements because I can't even identify what kind of object that is.  Ugh.  Any other ideas about what I can do to figure out what's going on here?

Comment: give me the source of that page.
I test it and it worked.
I think the page that you work on doesn't have table element and showing table in another way
(sorry for bad English)

Comment: It's GCP.  Here is a link: https://cloud.google.com/products/  I think the table is somehow being generated dynamically, but I can't tell for sure.